# Создать метод в классе, который будет принимать массив объектов пользователей, фильтровать и возвращать массив тех, у которых возраст больше 18 лет

Tags: php, массивы, классы, объекты, методы

У нас есть массив объектов пользователей.

```
$users = [new User('Tom', 17),new User('Bob', 20),new User('Den',25),
    new User('Jack',10)];
```

Необходимо создать класс, который включает метод, который будет принимать данный массив объектов пользователей, фильтровать и возвращать массив тех, у которых возраст больше 18 лет.

Есть рабочий кусок кода, не могу поместить его в метод внутри класса.

```
$under18 = [];
$under18 = array_filter($users, function ($x){
    if ($x->getAge()>18){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Покажите что куда и как вы "помещали".

Comment: Создал новый класс и попытался написать в нем метод принимающий массив/фильтрующий его и возвращающий новый.

Comment: что-то вроде этого, пытался и через ключ "age" и через метод прописанный в классе User
public function getAge(): string
    {
        return $this->age;
    }
class Control
{
    public function under($users)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {

            foreach ($users[$i] as $us) {
                if ($us['age'] > 18) {
                    return  true;

                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    return array_filter($users,"count");
    }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё намного проще, не нужно кучу циклов делать, и возвращать в них ничего не надо.

```
class Control {
    // static делает метод статическим
    // для удобства вызова Control::under($array)
    public static function under(array $users): array
    {
        // возвращаем отфильтрованный массив
        return array_filter($users, function ($user) {
            // оставляем только тех юзеров, кому больше 18
            return $user->getAge() > 18;
        });
    }
}
```

и вызов метода - `Control::under($array)`

если нужен не статический, то убираем ключевое слово static

`public function under(array $users): array`

и вызов метода

```
$control = new Control;
$adultUsers = $control->under($users);
```

или так

```
$adultUsers = (new Control)->under($users);
```

Comment: Работает, все действительно было намного проще, сам себе проблем создал.
Большое Вам спасибо!